# Does the right ventricle affect blood pressure in pulmonary veins?

Tags: blood-circulation, lungs, ventricles

Now, I know there are multiple things that push the blood through the entire pulmonary circulation like the contraction of arterial muscular walls... But what I want to know is whether the right ventricle pumps the blood even through the pulmonary veins, or whether its effect stops at the arteries.

This may not be of significance to be honest, but I got into a debate with a friend over this and thought people here would end this debate :)